# Javascript split remove ":" colon character

Tags: javascript

I have a string like this.

```
var a="1:2:3:";
```

I want to split it with `a.split(":")` to remove the ":" colon character.

I want to get this as the result:

```
["1","2","3"]
```

But instead the result of `a.split(":")` is this:

```
["1","2","3",""]
```

Comment: Split does exactly what the name implies... in this case it split 3 and null. Remove the last colon

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use this trim method to remove the trailing colon.

```
function TrimColon(text)
{
    return text.toString().replace(/^(.*?):*$/, '$1');
}
```

Then you can call it like this:

```
TrimColon(a).split(":")
```

If you wanted to you could of course make `TrimColon` a string prototype method, allowing you to do something like this:

```
a.TrimColon().split(":");
```

In case you'd like an explanation of the regex used: [Go here](http://rick.measham.id.au/paste/explain.pl?regex=/%5E(.*%3F):*$/)

Comment: for the sake of robustness I think you should use replace(/(^:)|(:$)/g, ''), in case the string is ':1:2:3:'.

Comment: @valentinas—why not make that an answer? It's a better option.

Answer (score 4):

Before parsing such string you should strip colons from the beginning and the end of the string:

```
a.replace(/(^:)|(:$)/g, '').split(":")
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to do it with RegEx as in the other answers, you can choose the one below and use it.

### Only remove empty strings

```js
["1","2","3",""].filter(String)
// ['1', '2', '3']

["1","2","3","", 123].filter(String)
// ['1', '2', '3', 123]

["1","2","3","", 123, null, undefined].filter(String)
// ['1', '2', '3', 123, null, undefined]

// Function
function RemoveEmptyString(arr) {
  if (Array.isArray(arr))
    return arr.filter(String);
  else
    return [];
}
RemoveEmptyString(["1","2","3",""])
// ["1","2","3"];

// Prototype
Object.defineProperty(Array.prototype, 'removeEmptyStrings', {
  value: function () {
    return this.filter(String);
  }
});
["1","2","3", ""].removeEmptyStrings()
// ["1","2","3"]
```

### Only remove unvalid elements

```js
["1","2","3",""].filter(Value => Value)
// ['1', '2', '3']

["1","2","3","", 123].filter(Value => Value)
// ['1', '2', '3', 123]

["1","2","3","", 123, null, undefined].filter(Value => Value)
// ['1', '2', '3', 123]

// Function
function RemoveEmptyString(arr) {
  if (Array.isArray(arr))
    return arr.filter(Value => Value);
  else
    return [];
}
RemoveEmptyString(["1","2","3","", 123, null, undefined])
// ["1","2","3", 123]
// Prototype
Object.defineProperty(Array.prototype, 'removeEmptyStrings', {
  value: function () {
    return this.filter(Value => Value);
  }
});
["1","2","3","", 123, null, undefined].removeEmptyStrings()
// ["1","2","3", 123]
```